# How to assign an exec result to a sql variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How do you assign the result of an exec call to a variable in SQL?  I have a stored proc called `up_GetBusinessDay`, which returns a single date.

Can you do something like this:

```
exec @PreviousBusinessDay = dbo.up_GetBusinessDay @Date, -1
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I always use the return value to pass back error status.  If you need to pass back one value I'd use an output parameter.

Here's a sample stored procedure, with an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourStoredProcedure 
(
    @Param1 int
   ,@Param2 varchar(5)
   ,@Param3 datetime OUTPUT
)
AS
    IF ISNULL(@Param1, 0) > 5
    BEGIN
        SET @Param3 = GETDATE()
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Param3 = '1/1/2010'
    END
    
    RETURN 0
GO
```

Here's an example of calling the stored procedure, with an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
DECLARE @OutputParameter datetime
       ,@ReturnValue     int

EXEC @ReturnValue = YourStoredProcedure 1, NULL, @OutputParameter OUTPUT

PRINT @ReturnValue
PRINT CONVERT(char(23), @OutputParameter, 121)
```

Output:

```
0
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: By using an OUTPUT parameter, you can return back any data type, the RETURN value from a stored procedure can only be an integer.

Comment: Just a side note, OUTPUT parameters that are declared with a value don't need to be passed in. This means that if you are altering an existing SP you can do it safely without risking breaking anything. eg ,@Param3 datetime = '1900-01-01' OUTPUT.

Answer (score 67):

This will work if you wish to simply return an integer:

```
DECLARE @ResultForPos INT 
EXEC @ResultForPos = storedprocedureName 'InputParameter'
SELECT @ResultForPos
```

Comment: -1 This will only return an integer. The OP wants to return a date. The accepted answer by @KM. is the correct answer, as it uses OUTPUT instead of RETURN.

Comment: Actually this works. The example as to how to get an integer that is returned, you can do the same for all other kinds (didn't check if table possible, but I think yes.) I just tried it for nvarchar(50).

Comment: @Mzn *"you can do the same for all other kinds"*, certainly doesn't work with `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Comment: @James Why? What's different about the uniqueidentifier datatype? Stored procedures cannot return uniqueidentifiers?

Comment: @Mzn `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` was just an example, `RETURN` is designed to only work with integer values, see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx). The recommended way of getting other data from an SP is to either return a result set or use `OUTPUT`

Comment: I am understanding you more now as the docs for Stored procedures (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) doesn't mention anything about returning "values" except through resultsets and  OUTPUT params... <code>return</code>ing anything other than an integer applies for FUNCTIONS and I wonder why is it working for PROCS even thought it's not designed to be used like that.

Comment: In 2016, this only works for int and nvarchar (or variants of the two).  Alas, that doesn't include bigint or other common modern primary keys.  We get to use output parameters or table returns as in other answers.

Answer (score 45):

```
declare @EventId int

CREATE TABLE #EventId (EventId int)

insert into #EventId exec rptInputEventId

set @EventId = (select * from #EventId)

drop table #EventId
```

Comment: actually the only working way decribed here apart from changing the stored proc's signature

Comment: Used this as well for a date, when the underlying Sproc doesn't have an output parameter either. (Underlying sproc had another Exec inside it from dynamic SQL)

Comment: @MichaelSander Totally right, all other solutions are **not** correctly answering the OPs question. The only way is a temporary table which holds the results.

Comment: Only way that works here without requiring edits to the proc, which I can't do in my case. +1

Comment: You can also use a table variable in place of a temp table.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) (assuming that you use SQL-Server):

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
DECLARE @returnstatus nvarchar(15);
SET @returnstatus = NULL;
EXEC @returnstatus = dbo.ufnGetSalesOrderStatusText @Status = 2;
PRINT @returnstatus;
GO
```

So yes, it should work that way.

Comment: in the OP's example they want to return a date, Stored procedures can only RETURN an integer value to a calling procedure or an application.

Comment: This is incorrect. That documentation is talking about a scalar function. The OP is asking about a stored procedure with its resultset. @KM. note even the source documentation is assigning the returned value to nvarchar(15), not int.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question. While there are good answers here I decided to create a table-valued function. With a table (or scalar) valued function you don't have to change your stored proc. I simply did a select from the table-valued function. Note that the parameter (MyParameter is optional).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyDateFunction] 
(@MyParameter varchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    --- Query your table or view or whatever and select the results.
    SELECT DateValue FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @MyParameter;
)
```

To assign to your variable you simply can do something like:

```
Declare @MyDate datetime;
SET @MyDate = (SELECT DateValue FROM MyDateFunction(@MyParameter));
```

You can also use a scalar valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestDateFunction()  
RETURNS datetime  
BEGIN  
    RETURN (SELECT GetDate());
END
```

Then you can simply do

```
Declare @MyDate datetime;
SET @MyDate = (Select dbo.TestDateFunction());
SELECT @MyDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for dynamic queries.

For example if you have more tables with different suffix:

```
dbo.SOMETHINGTABLE_ONE, dbo.SOMETHINGTABLE_TWO
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @INDEX AS NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @CheckVALUE AS NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT COUNT(SOMETHING) FROM 
dbo.SOMETHINGTABLE_'+@INDEX+''
DECLARE @tempTable Table (TempVALUE int)
DECLARE @RESULTVAL INT

INSERT INTO @tempTable
    EXEC sp_executesql @CheckVALUE

SET @RESULTVAL = (SELECT * FROM @tempTable)

DELETE @tempTable

SELECT @RESULTVAL
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my situation - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Table Variable for that

Code:

```
DECLARE @PreviousBusinessDay DATETIME
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(BusinessDay DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Temp EXEC dbo.up_GetBusinessDay @Date, -1
SET @PreviousBusinessDay = (SELECT * FROM @Temp)
SELECT @PreviousBusinessDay
```

> https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-variables/