# how to assign variable with exec string in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to assign a variable with what is returned from and "exec (string)" but am struggling with syntax. Below is some working code...

```
declare @iGeographyLevel int = 2
declare @iGeographyLevelID int = 64
declare @sGeographyName varchar(30)

declare @sSQL nvarchar(max)

set @sSQL = '
select Name
    from GeographyLevel'+ cast(@iGeographyLevel as varchar(5))+'
    where GeographyLevel'+ cast(@iGeographyLevel as varchar(5)) + 'ID = '+ cast(@iGeographyLevelID as varchar(5))

exec (@sSQL)
```

I would like to do something like...

```
set @sGeographyName  = exec (@sSQL)
```

Comment: Some might say it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245691/how-to-assign-an-exec-result-to-a-sql-variable which may be the case, but I want to avoid creating an SP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) is the best way of doing this.

```
DECLARE @iGeographyLevel INT = 2
DECLARE @iGeographyLevelID INT = 64
DECLARE @sGeographyName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @sSQL = '
SELECT @sGeographyName = Name
FROM   GeographyLevel' + cast(@iGeographyLevel AS VARCHAR(5)) + '
WHERE  GeographyLevel' + cast(@iGeographyLevel AS VARCHAR(5)) + 'ID = @iGeographyLevelID'

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sSQL,
  N'@iGeographyLevelID INT, @sGeographyName VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT',
  @iGeographyLevelID,
  @sGeographyName OUTPUT

SELECT @sGeographyName
```

The requirement for dynamic SQL here is a bit smelly though. Not sure why you don't just have one `Geography` table with a `Level` column (or possibly a partitioned view if the tables *must* be separate) Also Hungarian notation for variable names is [widely discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111933/73226) these days.

Comment: Naming convention is down to my company. Thanks anyhow