# How to store results from EXEC into an @variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had the same issue located here [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable)

My question is, how can I store the results returned from the EXEC statement into a @variable ?

Example:

```
EXEC('SELECT count(*) FROM ' + @tablename)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245691/how-to-assign-an-exec-result-to-a-sql-variable)

Comment: your question and example in different direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write as:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @COUNTOUT = count(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@COUNTOUT INT OUTPUT'
EXECUTE sp_executesql
@SQLString,
@ParmDefinition,
@COUNTOUT=@COUNT OUTPUT
SELECT @COUNT
```