# SQL Server : Stored Procedure Syntax mishap

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join

This is what I have to exexcute
`CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SalesByYr 1`. Parameter: `OrderYear`2. Display the `Total` sales for the `Year` by territory

`AdventureWorks2012` is the database.

- Sales.SalesOrderHeader table Sales
- Sales.SalesTerritory table

Here is my take: it results in an error code -

> Must declare the scalar variable @Result

What is the remedy? (The datatype for the output should be Money rather than Integer)

```
CREATE PROC sp_SalesByYr
    @OrderYear DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET         (SELECT SUM(@SalesYTD) SalesByTy 
                FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader a
                WHERE   a.OrderDate = @OrderYear  
                GROUP BY b.TerritoryID 
                )
    END

DECLARE @Result Money
EXEC    sp_SalesByYr '2002' OUTPUT 

PRINT @Result
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Territory=Name i would think would fail, you would need 'Name' would you not?  Additionally you have an output variable of Territory, but you're never assigning a value to Territory.  what is the definition of proc_TSales?

Comment: Thank you. Name does have to be in quotes.

Comment: What happens when you simply execute your sp without using any output variables?

Comment: EXACT same thing as with the "OUTPUT" attached. There is an error code after I run'print'- it says: Must declare the scalar variable "@catchSYTD".

Comment: I am still working on it, and I am sure that I will get it right. Pointers may come from this site; from else-where OR form within, but they will definitely come.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245691/how-to-assign-an-exec-result-to-a-sql-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE PROC sp_SalesByYr
    @OrderYear INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET         SELECT a.TerritoryID Territory,
                SUM (a.TotalDue) SalesByTy 
                FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader a
                WHERE   DatePart(YY,a.OrderDate) = @OrderYear
                GROUP BY a.TerritoryID

```
END
```

EXEC    sp_SalesByYr '2002' OUTPUT

Answer (score 1):

You may just need a "GO" after the END statement. The CREATE PROC is including everything until the GO and therefore including your test statements.

I made a few more changes, but made a few assumptions - maybe it will help.

- Change SUM(@SalesYTD) to SUM(TotalDue) so you calculate the sales for the year in the paramter
- Removed the OUTPUT from the territory assuming you're calculating trying to query by territory
- Changed the year being queried to 2006 instead of 2002 since there are no sales in 2002 in AdventureWorks
- Changed the WHERE clause for the year to YEAR(OrderDate) = @OrderYear
- Added to WHERE clause so territory is optionally filtered as well

Final code became:

```
CREATE PROC csp_SalesByYr
    @OrderYear DateTime, 
    @SalesYTD Money OUTPUT,
    @Territory Nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @SalesYTD = (
        SELECT SUM(TotalDue)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader SO
            INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory T
                ON SO.TerritoryID = T.TerritoryID
        WHERE YEAR(SO.OrderDate) = @OrderYear
            AND (@Territory IS NULL OR T.Name = @Territory)
    ) 
END
GO
DECLARE @Result Money
EXEC    csp_SalesByYr 2006, @Result OUTPUT, 'Northeast'
PRINT  @Result
```

Comment: Thank You, Jason Wallace. I have tried the code with 'GO' after 'END'. Now when I run the last part, it says that the subquery produced more than 1 value

Comment: You are getting more than one item back in the query when assigning to @SalesYTD because of the group by clause. Remove your group by and everything should run fine.

Comment: Thank you, Jason. Without the "GROUP BY" clause, I ran the following:   DECLARE @catchSYTD Money     EXEC Sp_SaleByYr '2002', @Territory=Name,@SalesYTD=@catchSYTD OUTPUT                            The result was a blank window with no value