# How to set value to variable using 'exec' in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @tags1 varchar(max)
declare @blockcount int
declare @blockstring varchar(max)
set @tags1='%Gifts%' Or CategoryTag Like'%Packaging%'
set @blockstring= 'SELECT @blogcount=count(*)  FROM M_PHBLogs where CategoryTag LIKE '+ @tags1 +' AND ContentType=1 '
exec (@blockstring)
```

I want to store the result of exec(@blockstring) into another variable like

```
@blockcount=exec(@blockstring)
if(@blockcount!=0)
BEGIN
    //something
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign an exec result to a sql variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245691/how-to-assign-an-exec-result-to-a-sql-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get sp\_executesql result into a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Not with EXEC (as far as I know), but using **sp_ExecuteSQL** you can define parameters and pass these parameters as input or output to the dynamically created SQL script

Here is simplified version of your SQL script

```
declare @tags1 nvarchar(max)
declare @blockcount int
declare @blockstring nvarchar(max)

declare @blogcount_out int;
set @blockstring= 'SELECT @blogcount = count(*) FROM UserDocuments'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @blockstring, N'@blogcount int output', @blogcount = @blogcount_out output
select @blogcount_out
```

Please read the tutorial [Use sp_ExecuteSQL T-SQL Stored Procedure with Input and Output Parameters](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/tsql-sp_executesql-with-output-parameters.aspx) for more detailed samples on how to use params with sp_executesql

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql`.  In fact, you should always use this function because it allows parameterization.

```
declare @tags1 varchar(max);
declare @blockcount int;
declare @blockstring varchar(max);

set @tags1 = '''%Gifts%'' Or CategoryTag Like ''%Packaging%''';
set @blockstring= 'SELECT @blogcount = count(*) FROM M_PHBLogs where CategoryTag LIKE '+ @tags1 +' AND ContentType = 1';

exec sp_executesql @blockstring, N'@blockcount int output', @blockcount = @blockcount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql`
Remember to `declare @blockstring nvarchar(max)`

Call it this way:

```
exec sp_executesql @blockstring, N'@blogcount int output', @blogcount = @blockcount OUTPUT;
select @blockcount
```