# Fill temporary table with procedure result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tempTable called `#tempPrueba` like this:

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| ID  | FiltroID | Planta |
+-----+----------+--------+
|   1 |       12 | NULL   |
|   2 |        4 | NULL   |
|   3 |        8 | NULL   |
+-----+----------+--------+
```

as you can see I have  Planta with null values, I want to fill it by executing stored procedure, when I EXEC stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC]
  @pe_BSCID = 12 --this equals to FiltroID of temporary table
```

It returns `Planta` value, so I want to execute this stored procedure with each `FiltroID` of tempTable and add it to column `Planta`. How can I achieve it? Regards

Stored Procedure:

```
    USE [SIOD]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC]    Script Date: 11/04/2018 11:39:16 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC] (@pe_BSCID INT NULL, @splanta varchar (100) OUTPUT)

AS
BEGIN

--declare @splanta varchar(100) =''
set @splanta =''
declare @tablatemporal varchar(100) = ''
declare @campollave varchar(50) = ''
declare @camponombre varchar(50) = ''
declare @query nvarchar(max) = ''

Select @tablatemporal = d.sNombreFisico from bsc.Dimension d 
inner join bsc.ConfiguracionBalance cb on cb.DimensionID = d.ID 
WHERE cb.mdEstatusRegistro = 1 AND d.mdEstatusRegistro = 1 and cb.ID = @pe_BSCID


Select @camponombre = 'sNombre'+da.snombre from BSC.Dimension_Atributo da 
inner join bsc.ConfiguracionBalance cb on cb.DimensionID = da.DimensionID
where da.mdEstatusRegistro = 1 and da.sTipoAtributo = 'N'  and cb.ID = @pe_BSCID

Select @campollave = da.snombre from BSC.Dimension_Atributo da 
inner join bsc.ConfiguracionBalance cb on cb.DimensionID = da.DimensionID
where da.mdEstatusRegistro = 1 and da.mdEstatusRegistro = 1 and da.sTipoAtributo = 'L'  and cb.ID = @pe_BSCID

set @query = N'Select @splanta = '+@camponombre+' from '+@tablatemporal+' as tt  
inner join bsc.ConfiguracionBalance cb on cb.FiltroID = tt.key'+@campollave+' and cb.ID = 
' + convert(varchar(10),@pe_BSCID)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query,N'@splanta varchar(50) output',@splanta output

SELECT @splanta

END
```

Comment: What's the end result to look like? i.e. what would Planta be updated from or to?

Comment: replace `NULL` value of temptable with value obtained from  stored procedure @scsimon

Comment: I understand that, but what does the stored procedure do? Can you post that code. You shouldn't have to do this one by one.

Comment: I added it @scsimon

Comment: Whoa, that's pretty wild right there. I'm guessing your data isn't normalized at all--can you explain why some values are in some tables and the logic behind this proc?

Comment: Yea, we are maintaining a very old system, it just getting data from different tables because each `Planta` value I want to obtain are in different tables  and different columns, very bad data structure @scsimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is a mask of how you'd do it with a cursor. I hope your temp table only has 4 rows, because cursors have terrible performance. I just can't figure out what you are doing in the procedure to transform it to a set based operation. With that being said, here's an example...

```
--create a cursor to loop through your temp table
declare someCur cursor local fast_forward for
select id from #tempPrueba

--variables for cursor and holding output from proc
declare @id int
declare @procOutput varchar(256) --change this to the correct datatype and size

open someCur
fetch next from someCur into @id

 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin

    --get the result from the proc for the first ID
    EXEC [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC] @id, @procOutput OUTPUT

    --update the temp table
    update #tempPrueba
    set Planta = @procOutput
    where ID = @id 

    --get the next ID
    fetch next from someCur into @id
 end

 close someCur
 deallocate someCur
```

Comment: In EXEC line I get error: `Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.`, we should change to `@procOutput = output`?

Comment: You need to make @splanta  an output variable in your procedure. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245981/6167855) or if that's not viable I can change it. let me know

Comment: `@splanta` is already an `output` variable into sp, look at execute of sp

Comment: It's not int he procedure declaration.... change it like so: `ALTER PROCEDURE [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC] (@pe_BSCID INT NULL, @splanta varchar(100) output)` and be sure to remove this line from the proc `declare @splanta varchar(100) =''` and change it to `set @splanta =''`

Comment: Here is more on what OUTPUT parameters are. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes I already have as you say. but get same error  at cursor, I added actual sp in question, now to execute sp I need to use 2 parameters like `EXEC [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC]
  @pe_BSCID = 12,@splanta = 12`

Comment: Odd... try this instead `EXEC [BSC].[ftNombreCortoBSC] @id, @procOutput OUTPUT`. I changed it in my answer

Comment: IT, WORKS, THANK YOU SO MUCH!.

Comment: No sweat at all

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure can only take one FiltroID value at a time, then the only way to use it is with a cursor that loops through the FiltroIDs in the temp table, gets the Planta associated with that FiltroID, and then updates the table for that FiltroID.

Comment: can you give some example of use of coursor in this case?  
it does not matter if you do not use my example, what I want is to learn and know what are you talking about