# Calling a stored procedure from another always returns data conversion error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

There might be number of questions regarding calling stored procedure from another stored procedure in SQL Server, or passing output value from stored procedure to another. But, I have a problem calling a stored procedure having output value, it always return error converting `varchar` to `int`.

Stored procedure #1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP1]
    @VarIn VARCHAR(MAX),
    @VarOut VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @VarOut = '20, 21'
END
```

Stored procedure #2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP2]
    @Var1 VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @InstNo VARCHAR(MAX)

    EXEC [dbo].[SP1] NULL, @InstNo OUTPUT

    SELECT @InstNo
END
```

I'm using right click on the stored procedure to execute it:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP2]
        @Var1 = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The error message is

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20, 21' to data type int

By the way, I got reference from the accepted answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245691/how-to-assign-an-exec-result-to-a-sql-variable).

Comment: What does `int` in `DECLARE @return_value int` do?

Comment: With the query that you have posted, you would not and does not get the error message. Please verify your query and post the actual

Comment: Because `@return_value` should not be not int, check the flow: it gets a `varchar(max)`

Comment: @SalmanA It is generated automatically when I click "Execute Stored Procedure..." from SQL Server Management Studio. The error still occurs when I remove that.

Comment: Dont delete it, change type. SSMS might not be prerfect on this...

Comment: @Squirrel Only insert and update in the query, I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @Aldriyan not sure what you mean by that. What I am saying is, the query that you have posted here is fine. I have tried it and it does not result in that conversion error message at all

Comment: instead of '@return_value' int use '@return_value' varchar

Comment: @ZorgoZ Do you mean changing it to varchar? As far as I know, SQL Server SP only return integer, so that's why we're using output parameter. But, let me try.

Comment: I am not getting error with SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1

Comment: @Squirrel It's strange, isn't it? I also have restarted SSMS, but still the same. Might need to explore more what causing the problem. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: You might not be posting the exact query that you have in your database. Create a new database and create SP1, SP2 in there and try

Comment: I am almost very sure that the last statement your stored procedure `SP2` inside your DB is actually not `SELECT @InstNo` but `RETURN @InstNo`.

Comment: in your SP1 can you declare the variable like this @VarIn VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

Comment: and @Squirrel is also correct that it should be `RETURN @InstNo` because if you do a select, you're trying to pass/return a table.

Comment: @Squirrel no, it's `SELECT` not `RETURN`. I might need to try your suggestion by creating new database.

Comment: @JCBorlagdan yes, I can. I have tried that and still goes the same. Thanks for your input. The problem seems not the query, but something else, Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: You haven't posted a true representation of your issue because that doesn't throw that error. I suggest you run each piece individually - first `SP1` on it's own. Then `SP2` without capturing any return values.