# How to assign a variable to the execution of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to assign the value returned from the `sp_formCreateEventID` stored procedure into a new variable (`@eventId`). I initially thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375666/1932324) was the way to go. This solution is also in line with the EXEC command generated by SSMS.

However, for some reason the `EXEC` line returns an `INT` from the stored procedure as expected, but when it cant' assigned it's value to the `@eventId` variable.

```
DECLARE @eventId INT
EXEC @eventId = sp_formCreateEventID @patientId, @programId, @clinicianId, @formId, @phaseTypeId, @draft, @dataCollectionDate, NULL
SELECT @eventId
```

`sp_formCreateEventID` (don't hate me, I didn't write this...):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[sp_formCreateEventID]
    @PatientID int,
    @ProgramID int,
    @ClinicianID int,
    @FormID int,
    @PhaseTypeID int,
    @Draft varchar(5),
    @CompletedDate varchar(40),
    @UserID int = null
AS
BEGIN


    IF @CompletedDate = ''
        SET @CompletedDate = NULL

    --for some forms such as Clinical Input - Initial, there should only have one form filled for a youth. If that is the case and the event has existed, just return that one.
    DECLARE @EID int
    SET @EID =  dbo.fn_GetExistingOnlyOneEventID(@PatientID, @ProgramID, @FormID)
    PRINT @eid
    IF @EID <> -99
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
        @EID AS 'EventID'
        RETURN
    END



    DECLARE @TxCycleID int
    DECLARE @TxCyclePhaseTypeID int
    DECLARE @TxCyclePhaseID int
    DECLARE @seqNum int
    DECLARE @NewEventID INT

    --if there is no cycle for this patient for this program, then create one.
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TxCycle WHERE PatientID = @PatientID AND ProgID = @ProgramID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TxCycle
        (OpenDate, PatientID, ProgID)
        VALUES
        (GETDate(), @PatientID, @ProgramID)
    END

    SELECT 
        @TxCycleID = Max(TxCycleID)
    FROM TxCycle
    WHERE
        PatientID = @PatientID AND 
        ProgID = @ProgramID

    --In this cycle, for the current phase type, get the max seq number
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TxCyclePhase WHERE TxCycle = @TxCycleID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @seqNum = MAX(SeqNum)
        FROM
            TxCyclePhase
        WHERE
            TxCycle = @TxCycleID

        SET @seqNum = @seqNum + 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @seqNum = 1
    END

    PRINT 'New Seq Num: ' + CONVERT(Varchar(5),@seqNum)

    --greate a new seq number under the same phase
    INSERT INTO TxCyclePhase
    (Type, seqNum, TxCycle)
    VALUES
    (@PhaseTypeID, @seqNum, @TxCycleID)

    --get the new ID, this will be used for the Event
    SELECT
        @TxCyclePhaseID =  Max(TxCyclePhaseID)
    FROM
        TxCyclePhase

    DECLARE @isFinal int
    IF @Draft = 'Yes'
    BEGIN
        SET @isFinal = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @isFinal = 1
    END

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM LoginPassword WHERE ClinID = @ClinicianID AND AccessID IN (1,3))
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ClinPat WHERE ClinID = @ClinicianID AND PatientID = @PatientID)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO 
                ClinPat
            (ClinID, PatientID)
            VALUES
            (@ClinicianID, @PatientID)
        END
    END

    INSERT INTO FormPat
    (PatientID, ClinID, FormID, TxCyclePhase, Date, Final, DataCollectionDate)
    VALUES
    (@PatientID, @ClinicianID, @FormID, @TxCyclePhaseID, GETDATE(), @isFinal, @CompletedDate)



    SELECT @NewEventID = Scope_Identity()
    SELECT @NewEventID AS 'EventID'
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your sp_formCreateEventID ..

Comment: Slight detour....https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a RETURN at the bottom of your procedure.

```
RETURN @NewEventID
```

Here is a complete but simple example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspExampleOne] 
@Parameter1 INT
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

RETURN 333

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
GO
```

and

```
Declare @MyValue INT
EXEC @MyValue = [dbo].[uspExampleOne]  111
SELECT '@MyValueHere' = @MyValue
```

Result:

```
@MyValueHere
333
```

But a better design IMHO is to use an OUTPUT variable:

Why?

What happens when you need a second OUTPUT? What happens when the needed value is not an INT?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspExampleOne] 
@Parameter1 INT ,
@OutParameter2 INT OUT
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

Select @OutParameter2 = 444

RETURN 333

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
GO
```

and

```
Declare @MyValue INT
Declare @OutParameterTwo INT

EXEC @MyValue = [dbo].[uspExampleOne]  111 , @OutParameterTwo OUT
SELECT '@MyValueHere' = @MyValue 

Select '@OutParameterTwoHere' = @OutParameterTwo
```

Output

```
@MyValueHere
333
@OutParameterTwoHere
444
```

Below shows what I mean about "future proofing" with OUTPUT parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspExampleOne] 
@Parameter1 INT ,
@OutParameter2 INT OUT,
@OutParameter3 VARCHAR(128) OUT
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

Select @OutParameter2 = 444
Select @OutParameter3 = 'Better Design With Output Parameters.  Not stuck with 1 return-value or data-type'

RETURN 0 /* everything went ok */

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
GO
```

and the call to it

```
Declare @MyValue INT
Declare @OutParameterTwo INT
Declare @OutParameterThree VARCHAR(128)

EXEC @MyValue = [dbo].[uspExampleOne]  111 , @OutParameterTwo OUT , @OutParameterThree OUT
SELECT '@MyValueHere' = @MyValue 

Select '@OutParameterTwoHere' = @OutParameterTwo , '@OutParameterThreeHere' = @OutParameterThree
```

and output

```
@OutParameterTwoHere    @OutParameterThreeHere
444                     Better Design With Output Parameters.  Not stuck with 1 return-value or data-type
```

Comment: Personally I much prefer using an OUTPUT parameter to the return value. In this case either works but the return value is limited to an int and is intended to indicate the status of the execution rather than returning a value. Excellent examples of both approaches.

Comment: Good call. That did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sean.  I agree totally.  You will always thank yourself (or another developer) later when they use OUTPUT variable over the gitErDone "return".  What happens when you need a second OUTPUT?  What happens when the needed value is not an INT?  OUTPUT is MUCH preferred over "return".  Except to "get It Done'rs".  They prefer easy-peezey.

Comment: I agree with both of you guys here. Unfortunately for me, this SP is being used by a method that is being referenced 99+ times. Thankfully, this project is about to sunset soon ;-)